# How to stop setInterval after calling a function in it

Tags: javascript, setinterval

So, I have a condition to check if im on a current URL. If it's true the `setInterval()` is started checking for one of the elements on the page.
If the element is found - function gets called. If not, it will clear the interval after some time:

```
if(document.location.href.includes('part-of-url')){
  var i = 0;
  var interval = setInterval(()=>{
      if(document.querySelector('.selector')){
        someFunction();
      }
      else{
        i++;
      }
      if(i >= 20){
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }, 100)
}
```

I clear the interval in case the element is not found but from my understanding of the `setInterval()`, it won't be cleared after I call the function and will keep running. Where would be the best place to clear it after the function gets called?
The whole purpose of this code is to run a function after element is loaded. I tried to clear it after the function call but the `someFunction()` code is never invoked then.

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: Add `clearInterval(interval)` after `someFunction()`…!?

Comment: @deceze I tried that. Edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the interval to be cleared once the element is found, just call `clearInterval(interval)` before/after `someFunction()`.

With that being said, it's preferable to use `setTimeout` recursively, as it won't flood your event loop as easily as `setInterval`.
As a bonus, you can use the recursive structure to contain the iterations counter *within* the recursive function's scope:

```js
function checkIfElementExists(i) {
  if (document.querySelector('.selector')) {
    someFunction();
  } else if (i > 0) {
    setTimeout(() => checkIfElementExists(i - 1), 100);
  }
}

if (document.location.href.includes('part-of-url')) {
  checkIfElementExists(20);
}
```

Comment: Turned out that the function actually was invoking, there was another problem. But thank you for that solution with setTimeout(), thats better!